# Obex file transfer (opp protocol) using obexd is very slow

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, yocto

I am using the obexd app that comes with the bluez stack in my Linux system to accept files from an android device over OBEX.

The file transfer handshake and download happen correctly and consistently but, the transfer rate is way too slow - of the order of 30 KBytes/sec. I need to transfer atleast 90 megabytes of data.

How can I speed up the transfer?

Comment: You can try to disable the Wifi on your system because BT and Wifi use close frequency bands and they can disturb each other. This said, my BT transfers are around 100KB/s, so you could invest in a USB cable.

Comment: What distance is the phone from the PC? Rates drop off rather quickly. Also remember that 30KB/s is 300Kb/s, so ensure you're comparing bitrates with bitrates rather then byterates.